# Volumetrics render different in viewport vs final render

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, lighting, volumetrics, hdri

When using volume scatter on a massive cube, with an hdr image for lighting, I’m getting wildly different renders between what I see in my viewport vs what I get in my final render.
[image: this is the final render]

[image: this is the viewport]

I thought at first I had something turned off in the viewport that was visible in the render but that’s not the case. I almost think it’s something to do with the hdr image and how the volume scatter renders in front of it? I can even turn up the density of the volume scatter until the viewport is nearly black, and the render will be just a slight bit darker.

I much prefer the viewport results and I can’t figure this out.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please keep only several objects of your scene (enough to see the problem) and share the file?

Comment: I have added the blend file, hopefully this can help determine the issue

Comment: In the file you share the volumetric cube is disabled for render, if I enable it I can't see any difference between preview and render, Also I can't see any image texture in your materials, I'm not sure it would make a difference, but I don't see the same thing as what you show

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with your render settings varying from your viewport settings. Could also be the number of light paths you have set for volumetric. I believe there is a weird bug with the volume being plugged into the world shader when using an hdri but if you are just using a cube then it should be fine.

Comment: To add to that answer from Isaac , there's a forthcoming fix mentioned in today's Blender Today Live video at [this](https://youtu.be/4FihO-WF0sA?t=812) timestamp which might be relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Camera Clip Start & End values to match my viewport's fixed it for me.

Viewport:

[image]

Camera (Render):

[image]